# wxPython application terminates creating the main form (Python 3.7)

Tags: wxpython, python-3.7

this is my simple application, the main body:

```
import wx
from QRformMain import formMain as formMain

def  main():
    app = wx.App(redirect=True)
    ex = formMain(title="Main Form")
    ex.Show()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and these are the relevant parts of mainForm and formMain classes:

```
class mainForm ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,333 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizerMainVertical = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        bSizerRow1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )
....
```

```
class formMain(mainForm):

    def __init__(self, title):
        super().__init__ (None, title)
```

formMain is a subclass of mainForm so that I can overload the virtual members related to the GUI that I am designing using wxFormBulder. In this way I can use mainForm without modifying it.
The problem is that the application terminates with exit code 1 at the 2nd row of the main creating formMain(). And I really don't understand why.
Any help will be appreciated.
Massimo

Comment: Shouldn't the first parameter to super().__init__(None, title) be self instead of None?

Comment: Well, after several trials I found that:

       super().__init__(parent)
and
       mainForm.__init__(self, parent)

both work.